# Am I correct in understanding that prior to measurement, a quantum particle does not exist and absolutely nothing exists?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations

Once I asked this question to my teacher, and he replied that in the framework of quantum mechanics it is pointless to ask such a question. He said that quantum mechanics does not describe ontology, that is, what "really is there" is simply a guide to how exactly a macroscopic scientist can interact with what is "really there." However, I often read that before measurement, nothing exists at all. What does the Copenhagen interpretation say about this? Is it correct that absolutely nothing exists before measurement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, I often read that before measurement, nothing exists at all. What does the Copenhagen interpretation say about this? Is it correct that absolutely nothing exists before measurement?

Copenhagen interpretation does not say "nothing exists before measurement". Such a view is pretty fringe.

Measurement in quantum theory is a process that creates permanent records somewhere - results of measurement. You can say these results of measurement did not exist prior to that measurement.

But of course the world and its parts exist whether somebody is measuring them or not. It is just that the nature of these parts is not so clear. Copenhagen interpretation assumes that quantum systems do not have all classical attributes at the same time, but measurement can bring some of them into "existence" at least for limited time. For example, CI would say a particle such as electron has no single definite (real number) position in general, but if its position is recorded on a photofilm (or its track is recorded as series of droplets/bubble in a detection chamber) then we have to conclude the particle had position pinned down to a very small region of space at the time it hit the photofilm/created the droplets/bubbles in the chamber.